# Showing Data with SQL Database Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I try to get data with local SQL Database. My 1st code workis simple and I write the path directly.

```
string connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\****\\****-\\Desktop\\MSSolution\\MSSolution\\DataTT.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

After some research I change my code to :

```
static string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    string connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + appPath + "\\DataTT.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

But the problem it's not showing the data.
And another question, the app will be deploy to an exe setup, so any problems working with local database

Comment: Have you checked what `appPath` is returning?  Does it match `C:\****\****-\Desktop\MSSolution\MSSolution`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContextName" connectionString= "Data Source=.; Database=dbName; Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Is this what you are looking for...?

Comment: no, just to know how to call a local database with path that will change on different setup

Answer (score 0):

Use the |DataDirectory| placeholder. Change your connection string to be:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DataTT.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

And then in your app startup, set the value of DataDirectory like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "SET THE PATH HOWEVER YOU WANT HERE");
```